Populating two arrays from a CSV file with each row containing two words separated by a semicolon
How could I fix my code that populates two separate arrays from a CSV file that contains words separated by semicolons in C?
My CSV file looks something like this:
to meet/encounter;begegnen
to care for/look after;betreuen
superior;vorgesetzt
to borrow/lend/rent;ausleihen

My function:
#define LINE_SIZE 100
#define STRING_SIZE 55

char **source_vocab = NULL;
char **target_vocab = NULL;

void allocate_mem(char **dictionary, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        dictionary[i] = malloc(STRING_SIZE * (sizeof(char)));
        if(dictionary[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("%sMemory Error. Exiting..", RED);
            return;
        }
    }
}


void populate_arrs(FILE *fptr)
{
    char *line = malloc(LINE_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr) != NULL)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;


        char *token = strtok(line, ";");

        token = strtok(line, ";");
        
        if(token != NULL)
            source_vocab[count] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";");

        if(token != NULL)
            target_vocab[count] = strdup(token);

        count++;
    }
}

Incorrect output that it produces:
English: to meet
German: ow/lend
English:  encou
German: leihen
English: nter
German:
English: gegnen
I've tried modifying my sample CSV file and using a TXT file instead. It didn't help. The function should perfectly separate my words into two arrays, e.g.:
English: to meet/encounter
German: begegnen

Please update your question with a stand-alone minimum reproduction program that can be compiled and run to demonstrate the problem. As it is, we can't see how source_vocab or target_vocab are being initialized. Nor can we see how your output lines are being generated. I will say that the line token = strtok(line, ";"); (second call to strtok) should not be there.

Here is one problem:
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr) != NULL)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                     wrong

It means "size of a char pointer". Typically 4 or 8.
It's not the size of the memory it points to.
So use LINE_SIZE instead, i.e.
while(fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, fptr) != NULL)

BTW: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition so you don't need to write it in your code.

That's one of the problems.  There are others.

@JonathanLeffler Okay. I didn't claim otherwise. If you spotted other issues, you could help OP by writing an answer.

I pointed out two strtok(line, ";") in a row, which is absolutely a bug. And I suspect at least one other, possibly two, but can't tell because he isn't showing enough code. For example, his alloc_mem() function. He doesn't call it anywhere in his code fragment, so we don't know for sure what it's for. But I suspect it is used to initialize soruce_vocab and target_vocab. I suspect OP intended to allocate the pointer array, but the code is written to assume the pointer array is already there, and it allocates empty word buffers, that are subsequently leaked when he strdups.
